# Nested Arrays Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I haven't tried nested arrays in javascript, so im not sure of the formtting for them. Here's my array:

```
var items = [
    {"Blizzaria Warlock", "105341547"},
    {"Profit Vision Goggles", "101008467"},
    {"Classy Classic", "111903124"},
    {"Gold Beach Time Hat", "111903483"},
    {"Ocher Helm of the Lord of the Fire Dragon", "111902100"},
    {"Greyson the Spiny Forked", "102619387"},
    {"Egg on your Face", "110207471"},
    {"Evil Skeptic", "110336757"},
    {"Red Futurion Foot Soldier", "90249069"},
    {"Wizards of the Astral Isles: Frog Transformer", "106701619"},
    {"Dragon's Blaze Sword", "105351545"}
];
alert(items[2][1]);
```

...which should alert `111903124`, but doesn't.

Comment: You're currently trying to put ill-formed objects into an array.

Comment: That's an array of illegal syntax units. Use `[[...], [...], ...]` for an array of arrays or `[{prop:value, ...}, ...]` for an array of objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
var items = [
    ["Blizzaria Warlock", "105341547"],
    ["Profit Vision Goggles", "101008467"],
    ["Classy Classic", "111903124"],
    ...
    ["Dragon's Blaze Sword", "105351545"]
];
```

to build arrays into arrays. No reason to change syntax because they're inside.

Comment: A `]` is missing, and there is an excedent comma (I assume that you just want to put the first lines but it's not very clear).

Answer (score 0):

Objects (`{}`) are collections of key-value pairs. Your object `{"Blizzaria Warlock", "105341547"}` contains values but no keys. Perhaps a better approach would be to give these properties descriptive names, then reference the items by property name:

```
var items = [
    {name: "Blizzaria Warlock", val: "105341547"},
    {name: "Profit Vision Goggles", val: "101008467"},
    {name: "Classy Classic", val: "111903124"},
    {name: "Gold Beach Time Hat", val: "111903483"},
    {name: "Ocher Helm of the Lord of the Fire Dragon", val: "111902100"},
    {name: "Greyson the Spiny Forked", val: "102619387"},
    {name: "Egg on your Face", val: "110207471"},
    {name: "Evil Skeptic", val: "110336757"},
    {name: "Red Futurion Foot Soldier", val: "90249069"},
    {name: "Wizards of the Astral Isles: Frog Transformer", val: "106701619"},
    {name: "Dragon's Blaze Sword", val: "105351545"}
];
alert(items[2].val);
```

`val` can be replaced with something more descriptive, like `points`.